# Нужно ли выделить запятыми слова "в широкую складку"?

Tags: пунктуация

Даже форму колледжа – клетчатую в широкую складку юбку, белую блузку и галстучек – она носила с достоинством леди.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Розенталь говорит, что таки да, нужна: "клетчатая" и "в широкую складку" - сочетание согласованного и несогласованного определений, не обозначающих единый признак...

А я бы не поставила. 8-(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может, "в широкую складку" - это немножко "синяя в горошек"? )))

Но нет, нужна-таки запятая.

***Даже форму колледжа – клетчатую, в широкую складку юбку, белую блузку и галстучек – она носила с достоинством леди.***

Comment: Абсолютно верно, не с двух сторон, а между определениями, если это не единый признак. А единый или не единый  - решает автор, кто его знает, что у него в голове

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо за очередную поддержку (а то одни наезды, у). Я очень мучилась с этой запятой, вначале написала "не нужна".

Answer (score 0):

Даже форму колледжа – **клетчатую, в широкую складку** юбку, белую блузку и галстучек – она носила с достоинством леди.

Запятая ставится **между однородными определениями, выраженными согласованным и несогласованным определением**.

Сравним: белая в клеточку скатерть, синяя в горошек юбка. Единый признак здесь определяет не автор, просто речь идет **о рисунке материала**, поэтому он и назван **единым.**

В приведенном примере прилагательные обозначают рисунок на ткани и фасон юбки, поэтому это не единый признак. В то же время мы считаем прилагательные однородными, так как они раскрывают общую тему.